# Example of combinatorial FSM?

Tags: parsing, grammar, state-machine, context-free-grammar, automata

On the Wikipedia page of [Finite State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) it shows a graphic of the automata types:

[image]

I've never heard of combinational logic being included in the automata theory, normally just the Chomsky hierarchy, which stars with FSM. How then would combinational logic be written using a state machine?

For example, if we have an `AND` gate, I'd see it in a circuit diagram as something like:

```
             ______
  A ------- |      |
            | AND  |------- C
  B ------- |______|
```

And the states would be: `1(A) & 1(B) --> 1(C)`, `1&0->0`, `0&1->0`, `0&0->0`. But this involves two initial states rather than one, and also the input to a 'gate' is the combination of two inputs rather than one, so how would this be shown using a FSM? I suppose it could be possible doing something like the following -- with the input symbols being `{0,1}` and the output `{0,1}` like a Moore machine.

```
    1         1       
s0 ----> s2 ----->  s3:1
 |        | 0
 ------> s3:0 --0,1--|
  0       ^----------|
```

But this seems a bit useless to me so maybe I'm getting it wrong, what then would be a proper way to model Combinational logic in a state diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a simpler way to diagram the above, where the Input and Output states are either `ON (1)` or `OFF (0)` to make it more intuitive.

[image]